# Android, Refrofit. Как разобрать JSON с неизвестным ключом?

Tags: java, android, json, парсер, retrofit

У меня такой вопрос, как разобрать json с неизвестным ключом?  https://acx.io//api/v2/tickers.json -  из этого json я хочу получить массив из двух полей base_unit и quote_unit.

```java
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
public class CurrencyACX {
    private Map<String, PairsACX> listCurrencyACX;

    public Map<String, PairsACX> getListCurrencyACX() {
        return listCurrencyACX;
    }

    public class PairsACX{
        @SerializedName("base_unit")
        @Expose
        private String baseCurrency;

        @SerializedName("quote_unit")
        @Expose
        private String quoteCurrency;

        public String getBaseCurrency() {
            return baseCurrency;
        }

        public String getQuoteCurrency() {
            return quoteCurrency;
        }

    }
}
```

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderAPI {
    //list from ACX
    @GET("/api/v2/tickers.json")
    Call<CurrencyACX> getCurrencyListACX();
}
```

```java
  private void addListCurrencyACX(){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://acx.io/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        JsonPlaceHolderAPI requestInterface = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderAPI.class);
        Call<CurrencyACX> call = requestInterface.getCurrencyListACX();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<CurrencyACX>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CurrencyACX> call, Response<CurrencyACX> response) {
                Log.d("myLOG","Succes");


//                Log.d("myLOG","======" + response.body().getListCurrencyACX().isEmpty());
             }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CurrencyACX> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("myLOG","Failed");

            }
        });
```

onResponse выполняется успешно, но когда я пытаюсь обрабатывать response, response у меня пустой.
Я использую библиотеку retrofit. Нашел в интернете пару нерабочих в моем случай примеров https://www.freshbytelabs.com/2018/11/parse-json-array-with-unkown-key-using.html  и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758601/parse-dynamic-key-json-string-using-retrofit. Может быть я не смог разобраться. Не понимаю в чем проблема. Заранее Благодарю!

Comment: а что пишет на вылете? вообще как-бы в чем суть - если вам эта инфа не нужна, то можете ее не извлекать, не обязательно все тащить

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.Map.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.currencycalc.CryptoCurrencyExpandableListActivity$2.onResponse(CryptoCurrencyExpandableListActivity.java:663)

Comment: я и не пытаюсь тащить все, только поля  base_unit и quote_unit

Comment: эту ошибку я исправил , оказывается я забыл инициализировать map. Но сейчас у меня map пустое

Answer (score 0):

Вы и не должны инициализировать `Map` - при правильно составленном POJO это должен сделать `GsonConverter`. В вашем случае `Map` должна быть корневым объектом response, класс `CurrencyACX` лишний, а `PairsACX` нужно вывести в отдельный java-файл.

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderAPI {
    //list from ACX
    @GET("/api/v2/tickers.json")
    Call<Map<String, PairsACX>> getCurrencyListACX();
}
```

---

```
private void addListCurrencyACX(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://acx.io/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
    JsonPlaceHolderAPI requestInterface = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderAPI.class);
    Call<Map<String, PairsACX>> call = requestInterface.getCurrencyListACX();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Map<String, PairsACX>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Map<String, PairsACX>> call, Response<Map<String, PairsACX>> response) {
            Log.d("myLOG","Succes");
            Log.d("myLOG","======" + response.body().isEmpty());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Map<String, PairsACX>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("myLOG","Failed");

        }
    });
```